# In CircleCI, how do I check whether a project branch is currently green?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

How do I check in CircleCI if a project branch is currently green (has no failures)?

I have looked at https://circleci.com/docs/api under Recent Builds For a Single Project and the "status" field, but when I try, say,

```
curl 'https://circleci.com/api/v1/project/rocky/libcdio-paranoia?&limit=20&offset=5&filter=completed'
```

I get a list and the status shows "failure". There was probably a failure somewhere along the way, but I am only interested in the latest build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Do

```
curl 'https://circleci.com/api/v1/project/rocky/libcdio-paranoia?&limit=1&filter=completed'
```

and look at the status. Note the limit of 1 instead of 20. That will give you the newest build only.

You can also look at the "failed" property. It is `true` if the build is red and `false` if it is green.